# How do we call 1:00, 2:00...?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, the buses leave at 11:00, 12:00, 1:00, 2:00...

We say they leave at (*integer hour*?).

If it leaves at 11:30, 12:30, 1:20, 2:30...

We say they leave at (*half integer hour*?).

Comment: Sorry, I meant 11:30. Already changed.

Comment: The word "integer" is not know to the general public.

Comment: The hour is always an integer.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bus leaves at zero minutes past each hour we say they leave "on the hour".

We can also say "at half past the hour", "at quarter past the hour" or "at twelve minutes past the hour" etc. as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! What will be the preposition for "half past the hour", "quarter past the hour"? At or on?

Comment: I put it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you every much.

Comment: In AE, I hear "Every hour *on the half hour*," and "Every hour *on the quarter hour*."